# How capture all System.out.println output inside my Android App as String

Tags: android, android-debug, adb

I have an App that uses various `System.out.println("Bla bla");`and I want that all these calls are captured and processed as *String* so I can view them in a `TextView` with something like

```
void updateTextView(String capturedPrintline){
     mytextView.setText(capturedPrintline.processPrint());
}
```

But unfortunately I don't know how capture ALL `System.out.println` without editing manually every method class to return the content of the print as *String*.

How could I achieve my goal?

NB

I need that app shows the System.out.println in the TextView itself also when runs in a device without any external debugger

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own PrintStream that captures all output using this method:

[System.setOut(PrintStream)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you give me some sample?

Comment: @AndreaF A PrintStream sends its formatted output to an OutputStream. You can easily create your own OutputStream that implements the methods OutputStream.write(byte[],int,int) and OutputStream.write(int). Let these write methods append the added bytes to your TextView's text.